# Portable 3D Web Technology?

Tags: 3d

I am looking for a solution to embed simple 3D scenes in a web browser that is highly portable across desktop and mobile devices.

I need:

- To draw simple shapes
- Shadows
- Coliision detection
- To manipulate    properties of the scene from the HTML page's Javascript. Such as move    the light position, move shapes.

WebGL provides all the functionality I need. I have built a simple [prototype](http://www.motherlovers.plus.com/webgl.html)
using WebGL via the Three.js library.

However, I need a solution that is highly portable across desktop + mobile devices and can be used today. I can dictate which browser to use or require a plugin installed - but it must work on pcs, ios, android, etc

I have tried the HTML5 Canvas but I cannot get any shadows - I think this will not be possible because shadows require hardware acceleration.

I have looked into a Java3D solution but I understand it is not possible to run this on mobile devices.

I would be happy with Flash if only Apple supported it.

Am I correct in my understanding so far? Is there any technology with which I can achieve this?

Comment: Mac desktops support Flash. It's only iOS devices which do not.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was incorrect in not making the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Cross platform is hard to get. HTML5 is not yet fully supported on numerous devices and browsers. I recommend you check JMonkeyEngine. This works wonderfully from all browsers, as long the platform supports Java.

Comment: The HTML5 Canvas seems [supported enough](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas) for my needs. This would be ideal if only I could create shadows. Is it possible to create shadows on the Canvas (without the hardware acceleration)? I suppose I am wishing for a software solution (library) that would run on mobile devices. Or would this be simply too cpu intensive for mobile devices?

JMonkeyEngine seems to run on only android mobiles. Although I have asked for confirmation on their forum.

Comment: Okay, well creating shadows can be done multiple ways. One can create shadows in 2D. I don't think a lot of browsers support hardware (gpu) acceleration yet with canvas, except Chrome that I know of. So yeah, better try something in 2D if you're going canvas. I don't know if it's quite what you're looking for, but check this: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/campbell/archive/2006/07/java_2d_tricker_2.html

Answer (score 0):

For better or for worse, "Flash" is arguably the "best" solution at the moment ... except for the iPhone exception.

- Q: Is OpenGL an option for you?
- Here's Steve Job's original statement about Flash on the iPhone:

  http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/
- Here's a link about Adobe's (upcoming) Flash replacement, "Edge":

  http://www.beatweek.com/news/8896-adobe-html5-iphone-5-release-date-sees-flash-edge/
- You might also be interested in Cocos3d (an extension of the Cocos2d):

  http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/

Comment: Is OpenGL an option for me? I do not know. I see OpenGL ES is available on a wide number of mobile devices but do not know if it is possible to access this functionality from the web browser. Can I access OpenGL ES on mobile devices from a web browser in any way? Requiring users to install a plugin is not a problem.

Adobe's Edge technology looks interesting. Do you see this being usable on a wide number of mobile platforms (as Flash is to desktops)?

Unfortunately cocos3d only works on iOS.